# Any idea why woocommerce_checkout_order_processed not firing when user is not logged in?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Working on a plugin for Wordpress + Woocommerce. Trying to run a function after order is placed and saved. Tried:

- woocommerce_thankyou
- woocommerce_checkout_order_processed

Tried priority:

- 10
- 5
- 1

What I'm doing:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'func_do_my_magic', 10,1)

function func_do_my_magic($order_id) {
    //Do my magic here using $order_id
}
```

What I'm expecting:

The magic to be done on each new order placed

What is happening:

The magic is done when the user placing the order is already logged-in, the magic is not done for guest orders or orders from users not logged-in

Any ideas on why?

Thanks on advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id){
//do some your magic here
}
```

Try this code..

Comment: Hi Aki... Same.

Comment: Where you are putting the code? actually it is working in one of my project.

Comment: Custom plugin file. The code runs for logged-in users, but for users not logged-in the code doesn't run.

Comment: if user is not logged in than does this function is called ?

Comment: Due to the fact that I'm using CoD, so, woocommerce_payment_complete didn't fire. woocommerce_checkout_order_processed, fires for logged-in users & doesn't fire for not logged-in users

Comment: try with new code. woocommerce_order_status_processing

Comment: Same. I think it has to do with allowing 'not logged-in" users to fire the action. Have you ever came across such condition?

Comment: Hi Aki, thanks a lot. I figured it out finally. I have a dependency on user role that affects running the function. Now working.